# how to install pysam in vscode? "error with subprocess.py"

Tags: pysam

i am new with programming and i want import these:

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import sys

sys.path.append('gumpy')

from gumpy import signal

but i got the error about pysam: No module named 'pysam'

i tried to install pysam but it shows this error:

Using cached pysam-0.22.0.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
─> [40 lines of output]

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

i have tried different solutions which was on the net like upgrade or downgrade pip, upgrade setuptools and wheel, install visual  c++ , cython ,...
but none worked. please help me.

I am using:

windows 11

python version: 3.11

cython: 3.0.7

pip: 23.3.2

setuptools: 69.0.3

wheel: 0.42.0